# 'Corresponding author' (coauthor) is irresponsible regarding submitted paper. Should I step back from the collaboration?

Tags: collaboration, withdraw, springer

I, and my collaborator (coauthor) from a different university had finished a work last year. We had submitted the full research article to one of the journal published by Springer. My coauthor was the 'corresponding author' for the same. We both had contributed equally to this work over a span of 4-5 months.

The article was submitted on March, 2016. Just after few days of the submission, the paper status remained as **"With Editor"**. Till today (now) the status has not changed at all (not even the date of the status).

I have been trying to convince my coauthor (who is also the corresponding author) to pull out the paper from such a badly managed venue and submit it somewhere else. However, he is reluctant and not interested to listen to me at all.

Moreover, I can't (shouldn't) directly write the e-mail for the withdrawal of the paper, as I am not the corr. author. Moreover, it may create conflict of interests.

I have been thinking to step back from this collaboration. Is it a good idea?

Comment: please tell us name of the journal so we know never to submit there.

Comment: @mystupid_acct I should not share that info. to defame the journal. May be, our paper got a bad hand at it!

Comment: By "step back from this collaboration", what do you mean?  The work in question is already completed. Do you want to be removed as a coauthor?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I want to permanently get removed from this.

Comment: I don't see any point of removing yourself as a coauthor. If the paper is eventually published, then you're better off staying on as a coauthor. If the paper is never published, then you don't have a paper, whether you remove yourself or not.

Comment: Write to inquire about the status of the paper yourself.

Comment: I don't have much to comment on this particular question. But I can't help but notice that you seem to get into an unusual number of weird situations in regards to publishing your work (I have even commented on this previously and that was many questions arising from such situations ago). I think you really need to figure out if you are doing something in a vastly different way than everyone else, because at some point, bad luck starts to be the less likely explanation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft +1. Yes, I feel the same too. May be I am in my early career and slightly impatient on these matters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're overreacting.  Good collaborators are hard to come by, so do not do away with a collaborator unless you have an issue with the academic side of collaborating with this person, not if you have an issue with a journal.

First, if you want to establish priority, send to arXiv or an equivalent site.  Next, simply tell your collaborator that unless he/she contacts the editor or the journal very soon you will do it yourself.  Your collaborator may be corresponding author, but it doesn't mean you cannot yourself ask for clarifications from the journal.  Lastly, you will achieve nothing by removing yourself as an author.

Now... you are in a frustrating situation and maybe you are just looking for an excuse to pull out or stop collaborating with this person, but that's another problem altogether.

Comment: *Now... you are in a frustrating situation and maybe you are just looking for an excuse to pull out*-- This is completely hypothetical. Have you ever waited for a hard-worked paper to get perished without review?

Comment: not that long but I've never blamed collaborators for it.  I don't deny you should do something; I'm just not sure at all about the wisdom of pulling out over this type of issue.  Moreover you can't resubmit the same work to a different journal.

Comment: Ok. Have you ever asked your collaborator to remind the journal office on the paper? And, your collaborator ignored all your messages just by saying "Let's wait for some more time."

Comment: again not that long, but I've pressed collaborators to "light a fire" under editors.  I do think your collaborator is not terribly reasonable - that's basically 1.5 years since submission - but: I've pushed collaborators to agree to a solid deadline to get an answer, with the understanding that if there was no answer by that time I'd do something about it myself.

Comment: @Coder **All authors are responsible for their joint papers.** If your coauthor is being ignoring their responsibility, then you need to step up. Stop whining and write the editor yourself.

Comment: This is almost a nonsense situation. March 2016? Is your coauthor different from everyone else? You should tell him to contact the editor now! I really don't understand. An error or personnel turn-over is most likely the cause.